# Is there a underscore.js lib for java?

Tags: java, javascript

I use javascript often, and find **[underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)** is very handy for manipulating data set, such as array or object.

I am very new to Java, and wonder if there is similar lib for Java?

Comment: You realise Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other right?

Comment: Half of that's included in the core language since 1.2, and much of the rest is available in Java 8 or Groovy.

Comment: @Miguel, yes. They are completely different things:) I was javascript developers, but have to work on java code on recent project.

Comment: Did you go ahead with the suggestion below or did you find a better way to accomplish functional programming in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can use Java's Stream class, which is a bit like Underscore in that it's designed for functional programming. [Here are some of the methods available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#method.summary), including map, reduce, filter, min, max etc.

For example if you had the following code in underscore:

```
var words = ["Gallinule", "Escambio", "Aciform", "Entortilation", "Extensibility"];
var sum = _(words)
        .filter(function(w){return w[0] == "E"})
        .map(function(w){return w.length})
        .reduce(function(acc, curr){return acc + curr});
alert("Sum of letters in words starting with E... " + sum);
```

You could write it in Java 8 like this:

```
String[] words = {"Gallinule", "Escambio", "Aciform", "Entortilation", "Extensibility"};
int sum = Arrays.stream(words)
        .filter(w -> w.startsWith("E"))
        .mapToInt(w -> w.length())
        .sum();
System.out.println("Sum of letters in words starting with E... " + sum);
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a library [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java). [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/SDb)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] words = {"Gallinule", "Escambio", "Aciform", "Entortilation", "Extensibility"};

        Number sum = U.chain(words)
            .filter(w -> w.startsWith("E"))
            .map(w -> w.length())
            .sum().item();
        System.out.println("Sum of letters in words starting with E... " + sum);
    }
}

// Sum of letters in words starting with E... 34
```